# 2D Zoom: Adjusting Distances Between Sprites

Tags: 2d, zooming, game-engine, scaling

I'm trying to implement 2d zoom for a basic game. I have the images scaling. I also have a basic zoom that fails on occasion. Like...it pretty much looks legit until you start testing heavily. Sometimes when I zoom in, and move two objects close to each other, and I zoom back out, the objects now overlap, although the zoomed in version suggests otherwise.

zoom_level starts at 1.

```
zoomIn():
    zoom_level *=1.2;
    for sprite in sprites:
        //make sprites 1.2 times their current size 
        sprite.x *= (zoom_level * zoom_level);
        sprite.y *= (zoom_level * zoom_level);
```

Comment: You zoom the sprites with the same zoom factor? Otherwise it is natural that they overlap when their distance is reduced. If you zoom them too and they overlap just by a few pixels, this could be rounding errors. Then you could try to generally round the size of the sprites with floor() instead of round().

Comment: The sprites are an aerial view. I want to zoom in to a section of the window essentially (then swipe around to view the sprites outside the current context), so I want them scaled by the same size and have the proportions of the distances adjust accordingly.

Comment: How do I adjust my code to make it so that sprites that do not overlap in one zoom level still do not overlap in other zoom levels?

Comment: It might get easier to understand the problem if you put two screenshots (zoomed out without overlap, zoomed in with overlap) somewhere. But I guess this is a standard problem with a standard solution, but my own knowledge is really poor there.

Comment: When I zoom in, there may be two objects that don't overlap. As soon as I zoom out, they overlap. In the short term I'm scaling the sprite size more than the distances when zooming in.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to give a proper answer, since no engine/platform/language is given.

### Explained in a general way:

You will want to scale the x/y coordinates of your sprites by the same factor as you want to scale their dimensions. And the corner closest to your "zoom-point" should be the anchor point for your scaling. [Meaning if you zoom in to the x/y-coordinates of your sprite it will be enough to scale the width/height. But if you want to zoom in to the center of a sprite, the x/y-coordinates will also change since they will be pushed towards the edge of the screen.]

But most of the time you shouldn't handle zooming/transforming by changing the sprites' actual world-positions/dimensions. Most engines use a "Camera" or "Viewport" to project the world-coordinates of object to screen-coordinates. Meaning they scale/transform all images at render-time, leaving the world-coordinates untouched. You should use whatever is the equivalent of that in your engine.

As an example, given a square at (1,1) with dimensions of 1x1, if we zoom in by a factor of 2 (effectively doubling everything) using the coordinate origin as the anchor, we end up with a square rendered at (2,2) and dimensions of 2x2 in screen space.

[image: a square zoomed in by a factor of 2]

### Specific to your given code snippet:

Why to you square your zoom level in this line?

```
sprite.x *= (zoom_level * zoom_level);
```

seems to be wrong, are you sure a simple

```
sprite.x *= zoom_level;
```

isn't enough?
And as far as I can tell, this will only scale the position of the sprites but not their dimension, you should probably scale their width/height too.
OTOH, if your engine already handles camera/viewport scaling, you probably don't want to change the x/y-coordinates of your sprites at all or else you might be double transforming them.

Anyway, I'd recommend reading documentation/tutorials specific to your engine.